# Error in MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, debugging

So I wrote the following code and im getting an error which says:

```
Error using ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in ==> Untitled2 at 28
edges =ifft(fft(song).*fft(myFilter));
```

This is the code i used:

```
[song,FS] = wavread('c scale fast.wav');
P     = 20000/44100*FS;                   % length of filter 
N     = length(song);                     % length of song
t     = 0:1/FS:(length(song)-1)/FS;       % and get sampling frequency
song      = song/max(abs(song));

% Gaussian Filter
x    = linspace( -1, 1, N); % create a vector of N values between -1 and 1 inclusive
sigma    = 0.335; % standard deviation used in Gaussian formula
myFilter = -x .* exp( -(x.^2)/(2*sigma.^2));% compute first derivative
myFilter = myFilter / sum( abs( myFilter ) ); % normalize

% fft convolution
song     = song(:);
myFilter = myFilter(:);
song(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
myFilter(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
edges    = ifft(fft(song).*fft(myFilter));
tedges   = edges(P/2:N+P/2-1);         % shift by P/2 so peaks line up w/ edges
tedges   = tedges/max(abs(tedges));    % normalize
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong here??

Comment: Have you looked at the error message? It says that your Matrix dimensions do not agree when you try to multiply `fft(song)` with `fft(myfilter)` using elementwise multiplication. So, what `size` are: `fft`, `song` and `myFilter` before you attempt the multiplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well immediately, your error tells you what line your error is at. So you go to that line. It also tells you what function is causing the error - "times". You don't know what that is, so you look it up in the doc file. Turns out it's the .* operator. Your error tells you that "the matrix dimensions don't agree" - what does it mean? Matrix, dimensions, don't agree - your two variables are different sizes.

```
song(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
myFilter(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
edges =ifft(fft(song).*fft(myFilter));
```

These lines are where your error is. You are increasing the length of `song` and then defining `myFilter` as longer than length of `song`, then trying to .* it (transformed) with `song`. Unless you tell fft/ifft how many points to use, you get the same size output as input, so this isn't going to work. I imagine you want them both to be the same length. Then, something like this should do it:

```
song(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
myFilter(length(song)) = 0;
```

I don't think you meant to change the length of song. I think all you need to do is:

```
myFilter(length(song)) = 0;
```

Instead of

```
song(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
myFilter(length(song)+length(myFilter)-1) = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, i wanted both of hem to be of the same length, as it should be in the case of fast convolution. I thought, i did have them to be of the same length. Thank you for the clarification. However when i make the change and plot again, i get the following error.

??? Error using ==> plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.

Error in ==> Untitled2 at 30
          plot(t,song)

which i didnt get previously, when i used functions, instead of turning the whole code to a script...

Comment: Because you've changed the length of song, now t isn't the same length anymore. I don't think you meant to change the length of song. See edit above.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you. I made the change.
However...... Now when i plot it, though i get a graph, I'm not getting a proper envelope showing peaks whenever a note has been played... :(

Comment: Ok. I'll try figuring out that. I do have one more question to ask. I've been using the "diff" function to find the peaks in my enveloped signal. When i use the code "W = diff(tedges)" it's supposed to return zero for peaks. I know this might sound like a silly question, but can you tell me how i can define the x and y axis to plot W, so that it has the same x axis as the "song filtered with edge detector"

Comment: Sure, I would use `plot(t, [0,W]);` or `plot(t, [0;W]);` (depends if W is a column or row vector). You could also do `plot(t(2:end), W);`. Btw for a continuous distribution, the derivative at a peak is indeed 0 as you say, but for a discrete distribution it probably won't be exactly zero, but will be small. Just a hint in case you were checking it `== 0`.